# Aggregating specific column grouping by columns based on condition in R

Tags: r, analytics, aggregation

I have come across a problem where i need to get weighted average of `$Access_score` if `sum $lives!=0` and simple av of `$Access_score` if `sum $lives=0` and 'Trx' as unique of each value grouped by `$IMS_ID & $IMS_PLAN_ID`

```
sc2=aggregate(nonsc1, by=list(nonsc1$PRSC_CID,nonsc1$IMSPayerPlanId), 
              FUN=function(x) if x$Lives=0 {colMeans(x$Breo_Access_score)} else {0} )
dt <- data.frame(IMS_ID=c(222,222,222,222,333,333,333,333),IMS_PLAN_ID=c(234,234,235,235,234,234,235,235),PLAN_ID=c(1234,678,1234,678,1234,678,1234,678),IMS_STATE=c('CA','CA','CA','CA','TX','TX','TX','TX'),PLAN_STATE=c('CA','CA','CA','CA','TX','TX','TX','TX'),ACCESS_SCORE=c(2,4,2,4,2,4,2,4),Lives=c(0,0,1000,200,0,0,1000,200),Trx=c(10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40));
```

My output should be:

```
IMS_ID  IMS_PLAN_ID TRX     ACCESS_SCORE
222     234          10           3
222     235          20       2.3333
333     234          30          3
333     235          40       2.3333
```

Comment: Please don't post images of data - copy and paste the data out of excel or use `dput(robjectname)` to get a copy-and-pasteable representation of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your new sample input and expected output, we can do this:

```
library(data.table);
setDT(dt)[,{ s <- sum(Lives); cbind(.SD[1L,.(Trx)],ACCESS_SCORE=if (s==0) mean(ACCESS_SCORE) else sum(ACCESS_SCORE*Lives)/s); },.(IMS_ID,IMS_PLAN_ID)];
##    IMS_ID IMS_PLAN_ID Trx ACCESS_SCORE
## 1:    222         234  10     3.000000
## 2:    222         235  20     2.333333
## 3:    333         234  30     3.000000
## 4:    333         235  40     2.333333
```

---

Here's a base R solution using [`by()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html):

```
df <- as.data.frame(dt);
keys <- c('IMS_ID','IMS_PLAN_ID');
do.call(rbind,by(df,df[keys],function(g) { s <- sum(g$Lives); cbind(g[1L,c(keys,'Trx')],ACCESS_SCORE=if (s==0) mean(g$ACCESS_SCORE) else sum(g$ACCESS_SCORE*g$Lives)/s); }));
##   IMS_ID IMS_PLAN_ID Trx ACCESS_SCORE
## 1    222         234  10     3.000000
## 5    333         234  30     3.000000
## 3    222         235  20     2.333333
## 7    333         235  40     2.333333
```

Comment: Appologies i corrected my question other rows for other imsids the dataset  has different IMS_IDs within that various IMS_PLAN_IDs i want for every IMS_IDS and its unique IMS_PLAN_IDs the score. Thanks a ton

Comment: Error: unexpected '=' in "nonsc1[,{ s <- sum(nonsc1$Lives); cbind(.SD[1L,.(nonsc1$Sum_RTLRX_TRX_CNT)],nonsc1$Access_score=" i am getting this error

Comment: The problem is the qualification. Remove `nonsc1$` from `Lives`, `Sum_RTLRX_TRX_CNT`, and `Access_score`. The qualification is not necessary, and in fact *must not* be there, because in the `j` argument of a data.table indexing operation the table columns (or the current subset thereof for an aggregation, as we have here) are automatically visible, and thus do not need to be qualified with the containing variable name.

Comment: Its data.frame not data.table infact data.table is throwing error when i remove the qualifications it says 'Error in `[.data.frame`(nonsc1, , { : could not find function "."'

Comment: Well, I wrote my solution to use data.table, so it won't work with a plain data.frame. I just edited my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Just added a base R solution, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bgoldst this worked however i have file with arnd 2mil rows when i run this code it exceeds all the memory and crashes. need to further optimize this

Comment: Which solution are you referring to? I wouldn't be surprised if the base R solution crashes, because `by()` is very inefficient. The data.table solution should be much more efficient.